# Geometry Nodes assign Named Attribute to specific points/curve handles

Tags: geometry-nodes, custom-attributes

A have a resampled curve with 3 points (ID 0, 1, 2).
I would like to assign a custom named attribute **only** to the point with ID 2.

Specifically, I would like to add a Boolean with a True value for point 2, and a False value for points 0 & 1.

There does not appear to be a Selection input on the Store Named Attribute node to accomplish this:

[image]

As a result, my custom attribute ('Curve_tip') is applied to all 3 points in the Spline:

[image]

Does anyone know of a way to work-around this, or should I just wait for a future update including a Selection input for the Store Named Attribute node?

Thanks!

Comment: If you do it that way, it should work: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XpT9H.png If that doesn't fit, I would ask you to be more specific about what you want to do.

Comment: I've been looking at this for over an hour and it never occurred to me to just connect the two Boolean sockets together!

Pretty embarrassed. Many thanks for the quick response!

Comment: You are welcome!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can solve it like this:

[image]

But if you want to capture the first or last point of a curve, the simplest solution is the node `Endpoint Selection`:

[image]

This selects the first or last point, or both, depending on the selection.

Additionally you can use `Boolean Math` to invert or otherwise process this selection.

Comment: Many thanks quellenform!